# How to handle a large input in an integer square-root method?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search, fixed-point, square-root

I need to implement a method for finding the integer square-root of an integer.

My platform is the Solidity language, where only integer-arithmetic is supported, and the iput size is 256 bits (`uint256`).

The typical solution is a binary-search, which I have implemented easily.

The problem is that my method is limited to input smaller than 2 ^ 129.

Here is my method (implemented in Python):

```
def sqrt(x):
    assert(x < 0x200000000000000000000000000000000);
    lo = 0;
    hi = x;
    while (True):
        mid = (lo+hi)//2;
        if (mid == lo or mid**2 == x):
            return mid;
        elif (mid**2 < x):
            lo = mid;
        else: # (mid**2 > x)
            hi = mid;
```

Note that I have posted it in Python rather than Solidity, because the majority of users here are not familiar with Solidity, so I figured that Python would be a good choice in order to allow others to easily apply changes on my method.

Nevertheless, I am generally interested in an algorithmic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in Java, rather than Python, purely because I already had this one lying around.  The code is simple enough to convert since all the variable are integers so it is all in integer arithmetic.

```
/**
 * Finds the integer square root of a positive number.
 * Crandall and Pomerance algorithm 9.2.11 (Newton-Raphson).
 *
 * @param num int Number to find root of.
 * @return int Integer square root of given number.
 */
public static int iSqrt(int num) {
    if (0 == num) {
        // Avoid zero divide crash
        return 0;
    }
    int x = (num / 2) + 1;
    int y = (x + (num / x)) / 2;
    while (y < x) {
        x = y;
        y = (x + (num / x)) / 2;
    } // end while
    return x;
} // end iSqrt(int)
```

Very similar to what you already have, but slightly simpler I think.

Comment: Ahhh, Newton-Raphson is awesome, I didn't know it could be implemented with integer-arithmetic. Will test it now, thank you!!!

Comment: OK, tested your method on `2**n-1`, `2**n-0` and `2**n+1` for every `n` between `0` and `256`, and it seems to be working correctly. Thank you!!!

Comment: Thanks.  It comes from my Java math library and I haven't tested it to that depth.

Comment: Well it's obviously not gonna work for that depth using Java's native `int` (or even `unsigned int`, which you may as well have used in your library BTW).